# C memory address - what is wrong with the code?

Tags: c, debugging, pointers, memory, memory-address

Someone asked me recently to see what is wrong in the following code and how should I fix it:

```
// Memory-mapped peripheral
#define STATUS_REG_ADDR 0x12345678 // 32-bit status register
#define DATA_REG_ADDR   0x1234567C // 32-bit data register

// Status register bits
#define BUSY_BIT_MASK 0x00000080   // Busy bit == '1' while peripheral busy

uint32_t get_value()
{ 
    while (((*(uint32_t*)STATUS_REG_ADDR) & BUSY_BIT_MASK) == 1)
        ;

    return *(uint32_t*)DATA_REG_ADDR;
}
```

I never did something similar before, so I tried to run it in an IDE and I saw that the return statement gives a segmentation fault, but I don't know how to explain it and if there something more wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you can read from that address on whatever computer you are running it on? (Is it a hard-coded address because of some architecture-specific reason?) Also, wouldn't `x & 0x80` be `0x80` if that bit is set, and zero if it is cleared? (and never equal to `1`)

Comment: So it was more like a challenge I had a couple of days ago and I could not answer it. And I really did not know how to answer it. So, I am asking, maybe, what is wrong in general with such a code and why?

Comment: please read [mcve]

Comment: And moreover, I do not get why the return statement is giving a segmentation fault. Is it because the memory address is not to be found? Or?

Comment: @lyst it would not be an infinite loop, it would be a never-loop.  It would not wait for the busy bit to clear.

Comment: You may need to cast the STATUS address as (volatile uint32_t *) to notify the compiler that the memory value could change independent of the instructions being compiled.

Comment: @lyst - on the debugger it seems that it never enters the while loop and that it crashes at the return statement

Comment: @e0k good call, I'll just be deleting my dumb now.  =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in `while` loop condition.

Your `BUSY_BIT_MASK` is 0x00000080. Anything ANDed with 0x80 will not be equal to 1 as it's LSB is 0. Anything ANDed with 0 is always 0.

You have to modify the condtion as

```
while (((*(uint32_t*)STATUS_REG_ADDR) & BUSY_BIT_MASK) == BUSY_BIT_MASK)
```

So that when the flag is set, it will be ANDed with 0x80 and output will be 0x80. (1 AND 1 = 1)

You are getting SegFault because the addresses you are considering are not valid on your computer. You have to take valid addresses. You are trying to access random memory or memory address which may not exist - that is reason for SegFault.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I now understand what is going on.